# Specification of "Facebook Safety Check/Crisis Response" being about the featured *Notification*

Tags: discussion, specific-question

For about [wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Safety_Check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Safety_Check) working through the question https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103217/will-facebook-safety-check-work-if-my-account-is-stuck-at-a-checkpoint-page, here is the research timeline:

Linearly blog-style going from the end to the beginning, (3) I asked about the "[fact of if a user [currently stuck on checkpoint] still gets safety notifications](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1497/22253)" on https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1495/is-fb-coms-safety-check-crisis-response-for-ai-stack-or-webapp-stack-if-zuc after (2) ["boat programming"](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1497/22253) with https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/10539/should-facebooks-safety-check-a-i-work-if-an-account-is-stuck-at-a-name-change led me to relearn the the scope of the original question at (1) https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103217/will-facebook-safety-check-work-if-my-account-is-stuck-at-a-checkpoint-page originally showing how I did not realize *I should have just said **"Safety Check/Crisis Response Notification".***

**The final word from that experience, is how I did not focus on the main feature/ability of the *Safety Check/Crisis Response* being about the fact of a "Notification", which then if I may ask again, gives here final scope.**

Quoting @AndrewT. from https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1497/22253:

> "After the back-and-forth comments on this meta question and the
>   revision to it, looks like the real question is
>
> 'I asked about the fact of if a user [currently stuck on
>   checkpoint] still gets safety notifications.'
>
> This is a clear question about the current policy of Facebook. While
>   this is off-topic on AI.SE, this looks like on-topic on WebApps.SE
>   based on their meta discussion: Are questions regarding website
>   policies on-topic?

Combine:

- "I asked about the fact of if a user [currently stuck on checkpoint] still gets safety notifications."
- "Will Facebook Safety Check work if my account is stuck at a Checkpoint page?"

=  Will Facebook Safety Check / Crisis Response Notifications work if a user is stuck at a Checkpoint page?
OR If a user is stuck at a Facebook Checkpoint will they still get Facebook Safety Check / Crisis Response Notifications?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking about. Is this question about the scope of web applications or are you asking about the scope of your question?

Comment: @Rubén based on the previous conversation on meta.AI.SE, I believe the core question that OP wanted to ask is "Do FB users on name change checkpoint still receive safety check notification?", and the purpose of this meta post is to discuss whether it's on-topic, or if it can be improved...

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks. I'm afraid that I'm still found this question unclear, maybe because I very rarely use FB. I hope that an FB expert come here and help to clarify the question and if possible answer it :)

Comment: This question was deleted by the system around 3/25/17, was undeleted by a mod (myself), and deleted again by the system on 4/1/17.  It's possible there's just no answer to the question available.  Otherwise, I'm not sure how to interpret this meta post.

Comment: @Rubén Resolved; I should have just quoted who helped me, their synthesis was instrumental to me going for re-keywording to the **specific "Notification fact"** (a fact/evidence for us to be able to authorize the question long enough, to get an answer and not just a crowd that constantly asks "what FB is").

Comment: @prosody-GabVereableContext this question doesn't look like a question about Web Applications main site so I think that it should be closed.

Comment: Maybe @AndrewT. is the better voice, please wait to hear if they can help.

Comment: @Rubén Thank you for adding [tagged/specific-question], I did not know the exact topic, first time with .meta just yesterday now.

Answer (score 1):

I have undeleted it yet again, but if the system sweeps it away for inactivity this time, I will not undelete it a fourth time.

It is truly possible that no one knows the answer to the question.

Comment: Mathematically how much time? Or another "wait and see who knows I do not know"?

Comment: ...technologically (is that not liable mathematically?), we cannot track that? Because the FB social code is proprietary or because there is a legitimate ("International Security"?) reason there is not any evidence? How is blood spatter analysis defined as findable, and then fully automated Artificial Intelligence-powered pre-recorded electrons we miss and can not find? The "educated populace"'s determined attacker is ignorance.

Comment: I believe it will get deleted either a week or 10 days after it goes inactive.  Please consult the mother Meta for details on the "Roomba" process.  It's "truly possible" that no *end user* (i.e., our site's experts) knows the answer, and in the history of the site, I don't recall any answers that resembled "I'm a Facebook developer and this is how we do things internally."  Honestly, I'm content to leave the question undeleted but I cannot promise any answer or that it won't be deleted again for inactivity.

Comment: What about being able to hear for a user saying "I'm a Facebook user who was in a Safety Check zone during a Checkpoint."? If that would be addressing millions of Checkpoint users reported (name changes are frequent too), is that enough fact-seeking?

Comment: @prosody-GabVereableContext Anecdotes rarely make good answers, unfortunately.

Comment: To state the fact, is anecdotal?

Comment: Severe if your answer to my question is anecdotal. To state the facts.

Comment: @prosody-GabVereableContext I think we're beating a dead horse here.  The question is open and not deleted.  If someone has some sort of answer for it, they can offer it.

Comment: @jonsca The question was deleted by Community two hours ago (one hour after your last comment)

Comment: @Rubén Thank you.  As promised, I'm not going to intervene again.

Answer (score 1):

Already posted this as a [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103217/will-facebook-safety-check-work-if-my-account-is-stuck-at-a-checkpoint-page#comment113771_103217) to the referred question...

> I added a bounty some days ago but it looks that it's not helping to get attention to this post. Once my bounty expires consider to add your own.

Reference

[What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)

Comment: I am thinking of adding link a to https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4619/specification-of-facebook-safety-check-crisis-response-being-about-the-feature and changing the title wording to say "feature" to help catch people's attention (or to help I mean, after realizing the original question still has the flaws now addressed but nobody changed the spotlight to the corrected keywords like "feature" and "fact" (on WA and AI respectively) that triggered the healthier response), is that a good edit idea?

Comment: I am surprised we gave a bounty before editing again? I thought the original question was unclear to moderation (we did not make group changes before "putting back to slaughter" again, and used 50 bounty already, "following the money [karma/reputation/points]"), and there is not a link to here from there. I am thinking about how much stable encouragement is being provided, and the speedy order of events.